# Trying to create a Bath file that will copy a specific directory path (no lower) and zip the directories in that path

Tags: batch-file, copy, rsync

So I have a directory structure that contains log files.  The path is something like the following:

```
C:\Path\TenantName\AppName\other\stuff\I\dont\care\about
```

What I need to do is to ZIP the AppName directory and everything under it into a ZIP file for each AppName under each Tenant folder.

So example is:

```
C:\Path\TenantName1\AppName1\
C:\Path\TenantName1\AppName2\
C:\Path\TenantName2\AppName1\
C:\Path\TenantName2\AppName2\
```

Would be (after the zip):

```
C:\Path\TenantName1\yyyy.mm.dd_AppName1.zip
C:\Path\TenantName1\yyyy.mm.dd_AppName2.zip
C:\Path\TenantName2\yyyy.mm.dd_AppName1.zip
C:\Path\TenantName2\yyyy.mm.dd_AppName2.zip
```

We are then moving the files to a Temp Directory that needs to have the following structure as well:

```
C:\Temp\TenantName\<ZipFiles>
```

The real issue for me is that I need to dynamically create the TenantName directory within C:\Temp as these will change.  Once the files are in the C:\Temp directory, I have Rsync moving them to a centralized server for long term storage.

Any help would be appreciated.

I already for the zip files being created.  Using the following command:

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "C:\Temp-Log\%DATE:~-4%.%DATE:~7,2%.%DATE:~4,2%_%%X.zip" "%%X\"
```

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there, you can repurpouse your `FOR` command to create the folder structure

try this oneliner in the command line....

```
for /d %d in (*) do @echo md c:\temp\%d
```

Comment: Yeah when I do that I am getting this: "\temp\d was unexpected at this time."  This is sort of the problem I was having earlier and I thought it was just me...  The variable is not working correctly.

Comment: C:\Users\Robert\Desktop>test
    \temp\d was unexpected at this time.

    C:\Users\Robert\Desktop>for /d \temp\d

Comment: I added it this way and it sorta worked.  for /d %%d in (*) do md c:\temp\%%d

Comment: This is a command line command, not a bat command. Change %d into %%d for it to run in a bat file.

Comment: What I mean by sorta is that it creates the top level directories.  So the directory has C:\Temp1\Dir1, C:\Temp1\Dir2\Subdir1. It creates Dir1 and Dir2 but not subdir1

Comment: Got it working by doing the following:      `for /d %%d in (*) do (
 md c:\temp\%%d
 cd %%d
 for /d %%e in (*) do (
  md c:\temp\%%d\%%e
 )
 cd ..
)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I developed at the end.

```
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    md c:\temp\%%d
    cd %%d
    for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "C:\Temp\%%d\%DATE:~-4%.%DATE:~7,2%.%DATE:~4,2%_%%X.zip" "%%X\"
    cd ..
)
```

This loops through a directory and makes a temporary directory structure copy and zips everything underneath their parent directory.